# Путь к памяти телефона на Android

Tags: android, unity3d

Делаю приложение на движке Unity.
Как выглядит путь к папке в памяти памяти телефона?
Например, мне надо получить доступ к следующей папке:

> /Android

На карте памяти пути таковы:

> /mnt/sdcard/Android или
>   /storage/sdcard/Android

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что у вас вообще туда будет доступ?

Comment: Ну на некоторых телефона есть встроенная память доступная. Там в браузере пишут: